# Pc power glows for fractions of seconds and doesn't starts

Tags: windows, cpu, troubleshooting, desktop-computer

I have a pretty old pc which I bought 6 years ago, from few months I'm facing a weird problem, my PC works fine for few hours then suddenly switches off and when I try to switch it on its power button glows for less then a seconds and nothing happens, sometimes fan moves a bit but still nothing happens so I need to wait for next 6-7 hours to use my pc again, I checked for heat sinks and thermal paste which are absolutely fine, I also check for CMOS battery which I already changed few weaks ago, what to do now?!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a possible power supply problem, often caused by aging capacitors that no longer can perform up to specifications. These kinds of faults often become worse with age: the problematic capacitor is currently performing just barely well enough for most situations, but as it degrades further it will probably start failing more often, until the system fails to start up at all.

If the desktop PC uses a standard ATX power supply (PSU for short), it should be a simple matter of e.g. borrowing a known-good PSU from somewhere and testing your system with it, as the connectors are standardized. If this makes the system stable again, you've found the problem and need a new PSU.

If the PC is a name-brand one (Dell, HP, etc.) it might use a proprietary PSU with non-standard connectors, in which case getting a replacement PSU might be harder.

The fault might also be in the capacitors on the motherboard. Look at the relatively large, cylinder-shaped components on the motherboard. If they show signs of leakage at their bases, or their top end seems to be bulging or burst open, that is a sign of capacitor failure. For examples, Google for ["capacitor plague"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).

If you are skilled in soldering electronic components, you might be able to replace any faulty capacitors on the motherboard yourself, as the voltages involved are small. But you definitely should not be opening the PSU unless you know what you're doing, since **the capacitors inside the PSU may hold a lethal electric charge**, even after the system has been powered down and unplugged.